# I used synchronized list, and i still get ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, vector, synchronized

I'm using `Vector` instead of `ArrayList` to make a list safe in multi-threaded enviroment. But I keep getting `ConcurrentModificationException` when I trying to add items to the `Vector` while iterating it. Why is that and how can I prevent it?

Comment: concurrent != parallel.  You can get a ConcurrentModificationException with a single thread.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot modify a Vector while iterating over it. Store the items to add in a separate vector, and move them to the Vector when the loop is finished or loop over a copy of the original Vector.

ADDED:
To get a mutex around the Vector in java, do this in both functions:

```
synchronized (list) {
  // modifying list
}
```

and:

```
synchronized (list) {
  // iterating over list
}
```

Of course I've assumed that the list is named `list`

Comment: Side note: this holds true even in single-threaded programs.

Comment: what do you mean it holds true in single-threaded programs?

Comment: You can _never_ modify the list while iterating over it. Even in single threaded programs. Modifying the underlying list invalidates the iterator.

Comment: so what the purpose of synchronized collections in this case?

Comment: None. It only synchronizes direct modifications and reads of the list. Which, in at least Java, does not include Iterators of the list. You need to use a mutex instead - locked for the entire duration of the loop, and which is locked while any other operation is performed on the list.

Comment: To prevent another thread from modifying the current thread's view of the list.  Note that this does not imply the list is immutable.

Comment: "*Store the items to add in a separate vector, and move them to the Vector when the loop is finished or loop over a copy of the original Vector.*" => or use an existing class of the standard JDK which does exactly that: a CopyOnWriteArrayList

Comment: @assylias That is not what that class does. It copies the list, throwing away the old one. What I propose is to wait with appending new items until the iterator finished.

Comment: I have one method that adds items to the Vector, and another method itareting on the Vector. I synchronized both, is that good idea?

Comment: Synchronizing methods will not help - as it only prevents that function from being run concurrently. It does not help with two different functions, they can still be executed concurrently

Comment: There is also recommended to declare synchronizing object as final, to sure that it's reference should be changed.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add items as you iterate, you'll want to use a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html). by using `Vector`, you're not bypassing this rule (*obviously*), so I would recommend using the `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I don't think it is safe to add while iterating with a ListIterator if more than one thread is involved.

Comment: @assylias, I misunderstood the question, I suppose. I was just addressing the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to iterate and add concurrently to your list, you should use a concurrent list, such as [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). Note that if you write a lot to the list it will not be very efficient.

Otherwise, if you use a Vector or a synchronizedList, you need to hold the list's lock while iterating. That will prevent the exception but it will also prevent concurrency...